# Third Party API is working on localhost but not when deployed to live server

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

I have an issue with an API I am trying to use. I did have a cors error but I managed to bypass that by making a custom plugin that would act as a proxy. However now I have a new issue, when I deployed the working site to a live server instead of returning the data it hangs for about 30 seconds then says "failed to retrieve data" which is a custom error message I made.

Cors is not the issue, the API key is correct (removed for this post though). I have no idea where to go from here. Here is my code

```php
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: DVLA Vehicle Details
 * Plugin URI: Your plugin URL (optional)
 * Description: Retrieve DVLA vehicle details using their API.
 * Version: 1.0.0
 * Author: Rob King
 * Author URI: www.majestic-web.co.uk
 */

// Enqueue the necessary scripts and styles (optional)
function dvla_enqueue_scripts() {
    // Enqueue the jQuery library (required for AJAX)
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'dvla_enqueue_scripts');

// Add a shortcode to display the vehicle details form
function dvla_vehicle_details_form_shortcode() {
    ob_start();
    ?>
    <form id="dvla-vehicle-details-form" method="post">
        <h1>Free Car Reg Lookup</h1>
        <div class="button-wrap">
            <input type="text" id="registration_number" name="registration_number" oninput="convertToUppercase()" required>
            <button id="lookup-button" type="submit">CHECK</button>
        </div>
    </form>

    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('#dvla-vehicle-details-form').on('submit', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var registrationNumber = $('#registration_number').val();

            $.ajax({
                url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
                type: 'post',
                data: {
                    action: 'dvla_get_vehicle_details',
                    registration_number: registrationNumber
                },
                success: function(response) {
                    $('#license-lookup-results').html(response);

                    // Reduce height of the license lookup section
                    $('.license-lookup-section').height(250);

                    // Scroll to the #license-lookup-results div
                    var scrollToDiv = $('#license-lookup-results');
                    var offset = scrollToDiv.offset().top;
                    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: offset }, 500); // You can adjust the scroll speed (e.g., 500 milliseconds)
                }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('dvla_vehicle_details_form', 'dvla_vehicle_details_form_shortcode');

// AJAX callback to fetch and display vehicle details
function dvla_get_vehicle_details() {
    if (isset($_POST['registration_number'])) {
        $api_key = 'APIKEY'; // Replace with your DVLA API key
        $registration_number = $_POST['registration_number'];

        $base_url = 'https://driver-vehicle-licensing.api.gov.uk/vehicle-enquiry/v1/vehicles';
        $headers = array(
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Accept: application/json',
            'x-api-key: ' . $api_key
        );

        $data = array(
            'registrationNumber' => $registration_number
        );

        $options = array(
            'http' => array(
                'header' => implode("\r\n", $headers),
                'method' => 'POST',
                'content' => json_encode($data)
            )
        );

        $context = stream_context_create($options);
        $result = file_get_contents($base_url, false, $context);

        if ($result === false) {
            echo 'Error: Failed to fetch data from DVLA API.';
        } else {
            $parsed_data = json_decode($result, true);

            // Fields to exclude
            $excluded_fields = array('typeApproval', 'markedForExport');

            // Display data in individual divs using a loop
            echo '<div class="dvla-vehicle-details">';
           
            echo '<div class="mot-tax-wrap">';
            // Check and display motExpiryDate first (if available)
            if (isset($parsed_data['motExpiryDate'])) {
                $mot_expiry_date = $parsed_data['motExpiryDate'];
                $mot_unix_timestamp = strtotime($mot_expiry_date);
                $mot_date_difference_seconds = $mot_unix_timestamp - time();
                $mot_date_difference_days = floor($mot_date_difference_seconds / (60 * 60 * 24));
 
                if ($mot_date_difference_days < 30 && $mot_date_difference_days > 0) {
                    echo '<div class="api-date-affiliate-wrap">
                    <div class="api-wrap bg-amber">
                    <p>MOT Expires soon</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="date-wrap">
                    <p>MOT Due:</p>' . '<p>' . $mot_expiry_date . '</p>' . 
                    '</div>';
                    echo '<div class="mot-tax-affilate-wrap">
                    <a href="#">Click Here</a>
                    </div>
                    </div>';
                } else if ( $mot_date_difference_days < 0) {
                    echo '<div class="api-date-affiliate-wrap">
                    <div class="api-wrap bg-red">
                    <p>MOT Expired</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="date-wrap">
                    <p>Expired on:</p>' . '<p>' . $mot_expiry_date . '</p>' . 
                    '</div>';
                    echo '<div class="mot-tax-affilate-wrap">
                    <a href="#">Click Here</a>
                    </div>
                    </div>';
                }   
                else {
                    echo '<div class="api-date-affiliate-wrap">
                    <div class="api-wrap bg-green">
                    <p>MOT Valid</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="date-wrap">
                    <p>Expires:</p>' . '<p>' . $mot_expiry_date . '</p>' . 
                    '</div>';                
                    echo '<div class="mot-tax-affilate-wrap">
                    </div>
                    </div>';
                }
            }
            
            // Check and display taxDueDate second (if available)
            if (isset($parsed_data['taxDueDate'])) {
                $tax_due_date = $parsed_data['taxDueDate'];
                $tax_unix_timestamp = strtotime($tax_due_date);
                $tax_date_difference_seconds = $tax_unix_timestamp - time();
                $tax_date_difference_days = floor($tax_date_difference_seconds / (60 * 60 * 24));

                if ($tax_date_difference_days < 30 && $tax_date_difference_days > 0) {
                    echo '<div class="api-date-affiliate-wrap">
                    <div class="api-wrap bg-amber">
                    <p>Tax Expires soon</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="date-wrap">
                    <p>Tax Due:</p>' . $tax_due_date . 
                    '</div>';
                    echo '<div class="mot-tax-affilate-wrap">
                    <a href="#">Click Here</a>
                    </div>
                    </div>';
                } else if ($tax_date_difference_days < 0) {
                    echo '<div class="api-date-affiliate-wrap">
                    <div class="api-wrap bg-red">
                    <p>Tax Expired</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="date-wrap">
                    <p>Expired on:</p>' . $tax_due_date . 
                    '</div>';
                    echo '<div class="mot-tax-affilate-wrap">
                    <a href="#">Click Here</a>
                    </div>
                    </div>';
                }   
                else {
                    echo '<div class="api-date-affiliate-wrap">
                    <div class="api-wrap bg-green">
                    <p>Tax Valid</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="date-wrap">
                    <p>Expires:</p>' . $tax_due_date . 
                    '</div>';                
                    echo '<div class="mot-tax-affilate-wrap">
                    </div>
                    </div>';
                }
            }
            echo '</div>';
            echo '<h3>Vehicle Details:</h3>';
            echo '<div class="other-details-wrap">';
            echo '<div class="other-details">';
            $resultCount = 0; 
            // Display the rest of the fields
            
            foreach ($parsed_data as $key => $value) {
                // Skip fields that are not needed or have already been displayed
                if (in_array($key, $excluded_fields) || $key === 'motExpiryDate' || $key === 'taxDueDate') {
                    continue;
                }

                echo '<div class="other-vehicle-details"><strong>' . ucwords($key) . ':</strong> ' . $value . '</div>';

                // Increment the result count after printing the current element
                $resultCount++;

                // Check if we have printed five elements
                if ($resultCount === 6) {
                    // Close the current "other-details" div and open a new one
                    echo '</div>';
                    ?> <div class="results-spacer"></div> <?php
                    echo '<div class="other-details">';
                }
                if ($resultCount === 12) {
                    // Close the current "other-details" div and open a new one
                    echo '</div>';
                }
            }

            // Close the last "other-details" div if there were any elements
            if ($resultCount > 0) {
                echo '</div>';
            }
            
            echo '</div>';
            echo '</div>';
        }
    }

    die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_dvla_get_vehicle_details', 'dvla_get_vehicle_details');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_dvla_get_vehicle_details', 'dvla_get_vehicle_details');
```

I have contacted Krystal support (my hosting) and they say my server is set up for sending API requests.

I have modified the code to display which errors the server is sending and I got this:

> "Curl error: Failed to connect to driver-vehicle-licensing.api.gov.uk port 443 after 132529 ms: Couldn't connect to serverError: Failed to fetch data from DVLA API."

Comment: Check if the live server has a firewall rule preventing outgoing http requests

Comment: Just sent a request asking them. Hopefully its just that